# Render to texture mipmap level

Tags: webgl2

I am trying to understand the correct approach to render to a specific texture mipmap level.

In the example below, I attempt to render the color cyan to mipmap level 1 of `texture`. If I change the level from `1` to `0` in the `framebufferTexture2D` call, the canvas displays cyan as expected. However I don't understand why only level `0` works here, because non-zero levels are supported in the WebGL 2/OpenGL ES 3 specification.

I've also tried explicitly detaching level 0 (binding to `null`) and various other combinations (i.e. using `texImage2D` instead of `texStorage2D`), but none of the combinations seem to render to the mipmap level.

```js
const
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
  gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2'),
  triangle = new Float32Array([ 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2 ]);
  texture = gl.createTexture(),
  framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer(),
  size = 100,
  vertex = createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, `#version 300 es
    precision mediump float;
    uniform sampler2D sampler;
    layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;
    out vec4 color;
    void main() {
      color = textureLod(sampler, position, 0.5);
      gl_Position = vec4(position * 2. - 1., 0, 1);
    }`
  ),
  fragment = createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, `#version 300 es
    precision mediump float;
    in vec4 color;
    out vec4 fragColor;
    void main() {
      fragColor = color;
    }`
  ),
  program = gl.createProgram();

canvas.width = canvas.height = size;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

gl.viewport(0, 0, size, size);
gl.attachShader(program, vertex);
gl.attachShader(program, fragment);
gl.linkProgram(program);
if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
  console.error('program');
}
gl.useProgram(program);

// Create a big triangle
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangle, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);

// Create a texture with mipmap levels 0 (base) and 1
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texStorage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 2, gl.RGB8, 2, 2);

// Setup framebuffer to render to texture level 1, clear to cyan
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(
    gl.FRAMEBUFFER,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    texture,
    1 // Switching this to `0` will work fine
);
const status = gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);
if (status !== gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
  console.error(status);
}
gl.clearColor(0, 1, 1, 1);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// Detach framebuffer, clear to red
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
gl.clearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// Draw the triangle
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

// Some utility functions to cleanup the above code
function createShader(type, source) {
  const shader = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
  gl.compileShader(shader);
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
  }
  return shader;
}
```

I expect that I'm doing something wrong in the setup, but I haven't been able to find many examples of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you want either

```
color = textureLod(sampler, position, 0.0); // lod 0
```

or

```
color = textureLod(sampler, position, 1.0); // lod 1
```

?

The code didn't set filtering in a way that you can actually access the other lods.

It had them set to `gl.NEAREST` which means only ever use lod 0.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
const triangle = new Float32Array([0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1]);
const texture = gl.createTexture();
const framebuffers = [];
  
canvas.width = canvas.height = 100;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

const vertex = createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, `#version 300 es
  precision mediump float;
  uniform sampler2D sampler;
  uniform float lod;
  uniform vec4 offset;
  layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
  out vec4 color;
  void main() {
    color = textureLod(sampler, vec2(.5), lod);
    gl_Position = position + offset;
  }`
);

const fragment = createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, `#version 300 es
  precision mediump float;
  in vec4 color;
  out vec4 fragColor;
  void main() {
    fragColor = color;
  }`
);

const program = createProgram(vertex, fragment);
const lodLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "lod");
const offsetLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "offset");

// Create a big triangle
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangle, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);

// Create a texture with mipmap levels 0 (base) and 1
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
gl.texStorage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 2, gl.RGB8, 2, 2);

// Setup framebuffers for each level
for (let i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
  const framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(
    gl.FRAMEBUFFER,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    texture,
    i);
  let status = gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);
  if (status !== gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    console.error(glErrToString(gl, status));
  }
  const r = (i === 0) ? 1 : 0;
  const g = (i === 1) ? 1 : 0;
  gl.clearColor(r, g, 0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  framebuffers.push(framebuffer);
};

// Detach framebuffer, clear to red
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// Draw the triangle
gl.uniform1f(lodLocation, 0);
gl.uniform4fv(offsetLocation, [0, 0, 0, 0]);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

gl.uniform1f(lodLocation, 1.);
gl.uniform4fv(offsetLocation, [-1, 0, 0, 0]);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

// Some utility functions to cleanup the above code
function createShader(shaderType, source) {
  const shader = gl.createShader(shaderType);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
  gl.compileShader(shader);
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
  }
  return shader;
}

function createProgram(vertex, fragment) {
  const program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertex);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragment);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    console.error('program');
  }
  gl.useProgram(program);
  return program;
}

function glErrToString(gl, error) {
  for (var key in gl) {
    if (gl[key] === error) {
      return key;
    }
  }
  return "0x" + error.toString(16);
}
```

Comment: I should have clarified in my question that neither of those work either. I left 0.5 in there when I posted the question because it should be displaying at least something besides black if it's interpolating between the two levels.

Comment: added another issue with `status`

Comment: Nice catch. I usually work in ES2015 where I use `const`/`let` everywhere. Is it alright with you if I clean my question up to leave just the filtering issue? The other issues weren't present in the code I tried to lift this example from, and I'd like to make it obvious that the filtering caused the problem.

Comment: You could clean it up but it seems useful to others. I'll leave it up to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144190/discussion-between-grovesnl-and-gman).